# SharePoint online: having a modern site as root site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site, root

In some situation one might want to propose to use a modern site (potentially a communication site) as intranet. If the O365 has been already established years ago, the site in the root domain.sharepoint.com is a classic one.

What is the least painful way to switch or re-create?

Provided you can create a secondary modern site at domain.sharepoint.com/sites/newintranet and redirect here, is there a better way to have the modern site (even a blank one) at the root site address?